# PSRR - Testing Fixture

Tags: sample-and-hold

I have to design a PSRR test fixture with a 2.4KHz signal imposed on a dc power supply. I can do it using a bias tee at rf but the size of the components at audio confound me. The application is a Sample and Hold Amplifier Test Fixture. I would like to stay away from transformers and/or large inductors since I probably have to wind them.
Any suggestions welcomed.

Comment: My suggestion is that your justification for not using wound components makes no sense; if you can buy the parts for a sample and hold amplifier then you can buy a small transformer.

Comment: depending on your current needs, you can just use an amplifier with some offset

Comment: More specs on voltage and current please.  Perhaps a power opamp would work for you?

Comment: define and list all measurements to be made. Rise time, droop, C value thus Z source , sample time etc.  No need to use inductors at these low f.

Comment: AndyAKa I would buy a transformer if I knew what to look for in specs.

Comment: Also the supply is 15 Volts, 55mA. I don't have the IC yet; it is a redesigned SHA which was obsoleted but now I have to test. I have to measure the entire gamut of parameters but I have a budget to buy parts for the fixture.

Answer (score 0):

Your audio bias-T is more difficult than radio-frequency bias-T, because the DC and AC sources contain frequency components not far removed. This situation requires much more careful design of the AC *and* DC power sources.
Power supplies most often expect that current will *always* flow one way. Current is expected to flow out to the load, and not backward (into the supply). Backward current flow is a possibility where a 2.4 kHz signal source is added to DC supply and Device-Under-Test (DUT). To absorb any backward-flowing current, a big swamping capacitor might be added to power supply output:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIo9GV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
It is quite possible that DUT contains capacitance between its DC power input and power return. The parallel impedance of DC supply plus swamping capacitor should be *very much smaller* than DUT internal capacitance. In addition, the AC source must have a low output impedance to drive DUT capacitive load. The AC source might be required to have a low output impedance at much higher frequencies as well, if DUT draws transient currents - a likely possibility for some sample-and-hold circuits. AndyAka's suggestion of a step-down audio transformer is a good solution for a low-impedance AC source. A small transformer can likely cope with DC current flowing through its small number of turns on its low-impedance winding.
If DC plus peak AC current requirements are reasonably low, a power op-amp might be used to combine DC and AC sources. Output impedance can be quite low in the audio frequency range, but some op-amps become unstable when presented with capacitive loads. Try to measure peak current requirements of your DUT before approaching design decisions.